# Vue updating components at the same time after push

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am building a form in `Vue`

I have a component that looks as follow:

```
<template>
    <transition name="preview-pane">
    <label>{{ option.group }}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
         :name="`group_name[${index}]`"
         v-on:input="option.group = $event.target.value"
         :value="option.group">
               
    <a ref="#" class="btn btn-primary float-right" @click="$emit('copy')" role="button">{{ __('Copy') }} </a>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            option: {
                group: ''
            },
            index: {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

My `Vue` instance is as follow:

```
var products = new Vue({
    el: '#products',
    data: {
        options: []
    },
    methods: {
        add() {
            this.options.push({
                group: ''
            })
        },
        copy(index) {
            this.options.push(this.options[index])
        }
    }
})
```

And last my html looks as follow

```
<product-option 
   v-for="(option, index) in options" 
   :key="index"
   :option="option"
   :index="index"
   @copy="copy(index)">
</product-option>
```

I have one button that basically takes one of the options and push it once again (copy method on the `vue` instance). When I run everything seems fine but then when I change the input it update the props of all the components that have been copied.

What can I do to make vue understand that each component should work separately?

Comment: you are not copying with `this.options.push(this.options[index])`

Comment: @Estradiaz yes it works, what do u mean?

Comment: try `let opts = [{value: 1}]; opts.push(opts[0]); opts[0].value = 2; console.log(opts[1].value) //2`

Comment: it still wont achieve what I need

Answer (score 0):

Well in case someone have the same issue, I sort it out like this:

```
copy(index) {
    var object = this.options[index]
    var newObject = {}
    for (const property in object) {
        newObject[property] = object[property]
    }
    this.options.push(newObject)
}
```